# Uninitialized constant in model affecting controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I am working on a test application in which someone who favors something becomes a subscriber of that person.

The controller:

```
  def favorite_subscribe
    @favorite_subscription = FavoriteSubscription.add_favorite_subscription(current_user, @user)
    @user.favorite_subscriber_total = @user.favorite_subscriber_total + 1
    @user.save
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Congratulations, you have favorited #{@user.username}."
  end
```

The model:

```
def self.add_favorite_subscription(user, favorite_subscribe)
  user.favorite_subscriptions.where(:subscribe_id => subscribe.id).first_or_create
end

  # Remove the favorite of the user with the other user
  def self.remove_favorite_subscription(user, favorite_subscribe)
    user.favorite_subscriptions.where(:subscribe_id => subscribe.id).destroy_all
  end

  # Get the user with the subscription
  def favorite_subscribe
    User.find(subscribe_id)
  end
```

I get an error that it cannot autoload constant, and that it expects my model to define it. If anybody can help that would be very appreciated.

Error is here, sorry about that:

```
Unable to autoload constant FavoriteSubscription, expected /home/jakxna360/rails/test/app/models/favorite_subscription.rb to define it
```

Comment: and try to include the model and controller definitions as well.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the error here.

Comment: What is file name/path of your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that Rails is unable to find the file in which some class is defined and therefore autoloading fails. Rails is very strict about its conventions.

In the context of the posted code, I suggest double checking that

1. the `class FavoriteSubscription` (singular) is defined in a file named `app/models/favorite_subscription.rb` (singular), that a database table is named  `favorite_subscriptions` (plural) and that is exists.
2. the `FavoriteSubscriptionsController` (plural) is defined in a file named `app/controllers/favorite_subscriptions_controller.rb` (plural).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. The class Favoritesubscription is defined in the model. and the user is also defined. If it helps the subscription belongs to the user

Comment: Uppercase, lowercase and underscores are important: Is you class named `Favoritesubscription` or `FavoriteSubscription`. Is the file name `favoritesubscription.rb` or `favorite_subscription.rb`?

Comment: The file name for the controller is favoritesubscription.rb. The file name for the model is favorite_subscription.rb. I also found that the class in active record is called Favoritesubscription and in the controller it's FavoriteSubscriptionsController.

Comment: There you have your answer: Fix the inconsistency in the naming like a described in my answer and pay extra attention to singular, plural, snake_case and uppercase namings...

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know you have to have the same exact filename